# How to fetch latest neovim appimage from terminal?

Tags: neovim, installing

I would like write a script that automatically fetches the latest Neovim Appimage from the [releases page](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases), I was trying to see if I can use wget to access the latest appimage, but that would require me to know the latest version before running the command (if I wanted to create the URL myself).

e.g. https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/download/v0.6.1/nvim.appimage

Is there a way to do this? I'd also like to fetch the sha256sums along with the appimage as well (so a general method to download the latest assets also works).

Comment: I have a script with nightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the url `https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/latest` automatically redirects to the latest version URL. So I wrote a script that extracts the version and downloads the assets.

As long as the neovim team doesn't modify their repo paths, it should keep working:

```
nvim_latest_version=$(curl -s https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/latest | grep -Po '".*"' )                                                                                                         
# get version                                                                                                                                                                                              
nvim_latest_version="${nvim_latest_version:47:-1}"                                                                                                                                                         
# get download link                                                                                                                                                                                        
nvim_base_download_link=https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/download/${nvim_latest_version}                                                                                                          
# append assets                                                                                                                                                                                            
nvim_appimage_link=$nvim_base_download_link/nvim.appimage                                                                                                                                                  
nvim_appimage_checksum_link=$nvim_base_download_link/nvim.appimage.sha256sum                                                                                                                               
nvim_linux64_link=$nvim_base_download_link/nvim-linux64.tar.gz                                                                                                                                             
nvim_linux64_checksum_link=$nvim_base_download_link/nvim-linux64.tar.gz.sha256sum                                                                                                                          
# download                                                                                                                                                                                                 
wget $nvim_appimage_link                                                                                                                                                                                   
wget $nvim_appimage_checksum_link                                                                                                                                                                          
wget $nvim_linux64_link                                                                                                                                                                                    
wget $nvim_linux64_checksum_link                                                                                                                                                                           
# check shasums                                                                                                                                                                                            
sha256sum -c nvim.appimage.sha256sum                                                                                                                                                                       
sha256sum -c nvim-linux64.tar.gz.sha256sum
```